# How do I invert the return code of grep in C shell?

Tags: csh

I have a script like this:

```
#!csh -e
./build >& build.log
grep -q "BUILD FAILED" build.log
```

I want to exit non-zero if the string "BUILD FAILED" was found but grep returns 0 if the string was found. How can I invert the return code?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest you can do is negotiate the output with "!":

```
! grep -q "BUILD FAILED" build.log
```

The problem is that the return code 2 (which means file not found) is not handled. The proper way to do it is like this:

```
grep -q "BUILD FAILED" build.log || test $? != 2 && ! grep -q "BUILD FAILED" build.log
```

Here we are first checking if the return code was a 2, if yes we get the exit code 1 from `test $? != 2`. If grep returned not 2, the final grep is executed, which returns the desired check.

This is working in bash, I hope it's also working in C shell.